# Does `docker run --rm cli_command` destroy SSDs via constant writing?

Tags: docker, ssd

I am running several PHP CLI apps (phpcs, phpunit, phpstan, to name a few) via `docker run -it --rm` against several hundred thousand packages.

This means an equivalent of millions of `docker run`s over the course of a year.

Does `docker run -it --rm` chew up my SSD drive?

If so: Is there an alternative that keeps the containers alive but uses different $PWD and CLI arguments for each run?

Comment: Which storage driver did you use?

Comment: It is using the default, overlay2, tho I could make it it's own btrfs, but reading the docs, it says btrfs parts fill up with frequent container creation.

Comment: overlay2 should be fine if you aren't deleting and recreating the images all the time. Nothing can save your SSD if you are.